# Mocha exit from before function if condition does not match

Tags: mocha.js, chai

In below logic for code (sorry did not copy the exact code) I want to exit the test if 'xyz' data is not found in any file. Basically want to exit when the 'if' condition does not execute for a single file.

```
 private testFileNames(testFiles: string[]) {
     const self = this;
   describe('test', async function() {
       before(async function() {
           for (let testFile of testFiles) {
            //read data from file

            if (find xyz data in file) {
            //set up test
            }
            // code to add listeners
        }
}
 ////Want to exit here after for loop finishes and if xyz data is not found in any file
});


    it(`test should complete without errors`, async function() {
        //some code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a new error in the `before` hook when use it with `async/await`. Or, pass an error argument to [done()](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) function. This will exit the test and will not run the subsequent test cases.

E.g.

```js
describe('test', function () {
  before(async function () {
    const xyz = 'd';
    const file = 'aa';
    if (!file.includes(xyz)) {
      throw new Error(`exit test. reason: '${xyz}' data not found`);
    }
  });

  it('should pass 1', () => {});
  it('should pass 2', () => {});
  it('should pass 3', () => {});
});
```

test result shows the error happened in the `before` hook:

```
  test
    1) "before all" hook for "should pass 1"


  0 passing (137ms)
  1 failing

  1) test
       "before all" hook for "should pass 1":
     Error: exit test. reason: 'd' data not found
      at Context.<anonymous> (src/stackoverflow/61846578/index.test.ts:6:13)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/61846578/index.test.ts:8:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (src/stackoverflow/61846578/index.test.ts:4:12)
      at Context.<anonymous> (src/stackoverflow/61846578/index.test.ts:13:16)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```